# I want to move the price of treatment to the right instead of left but i don't know how

Tags: php, html

```
The Database Code    
<?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "halcondentalclinic";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `payment` WHERE patient_id='$id'";

    $conn->multi_query($sql);
    $result = $conn->use_result();

    echo $conn->error; 
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $treatments = $row['treatment'];
    $treatmentss = $row['totalprice'];
    $treatments_chunks = explode(",", $treatments);
    $treatments_chunkss = explode(",", $treatmentss);
    ?>
```

For PHP code and declaration of variables ------------------------------qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq

```
 <table class="table table-bordered"    width="50%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead><th> Teeth</th>
          <th> Price</th>
        </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>

     <?php 
foreach($treatments_chunks as $row   ){
     echo '<tr>';
    $row = explode(',',$row);

foreach($row as $cell ){

    echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';

    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }

?>
 <?php 
foreach($treatments_chunkss as $row   ){
     echo '<tr>';
    $row = explode(',',$row);

foreach($row as $cell ){

    echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';

    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }

?>

  </tbody>
```

For table code --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**OUTPUT**
[image]

[Table for payment in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLHR5.png)

Comment: Post your data structure or your array values plz

Comment: done sir I already post my table

Comment: As an aside, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

I added some SQL injection protection to your select query because the $id parameter is never checked for any input validation, you might want to check if its actually a number. Always assume the user wants to harm the program, because sooner or later somebody might.

The reason why the rows are only below eachother is because the TR causes a next row. The TD causes a next column. and you tell it to always make a new column in a loop function.

-This code below is unchecked by the compiler.

```
The Database Code
<?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "halcondentalclinic";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($mysqli->connect_error) {
    exit('Error connecting to database'); //Should be a message a typical user could understand in production
    }

    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `payment` WHERE patient_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
?>
```

Debug the variables if its not working with var_debug($row); and temporarily put exit; below the debug line so you quickly see a single variable in php.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="50%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <th>Teeth</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['treatment'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['totalprice'].'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please read the below article about MySQLi prepared statements and or google more information about on how to use them, they are more secure as your current way of retrieving data.

Source:
https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score -1):

In PHP:

```
$row['treatment'] = explode(",", $row['treatment']);
$row['totalprice'] = explode(",", $row['totalprice']);
```

In HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>

<?php 
foreach($row['treatment'] as $key => $value){
    echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['totalprice'][$key].'</td>';
}
?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I would not split up the Array, unless he made the DB information cells like : "100,200,500,300,800" Which would not be the way to make a DB and split that cell up in a different table and use a left join to merge it in instead.